# Map 2D array into 1D array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

For fun, I am trying to represent a **2D** array in **1D** array. How can I map a 2-dimensional array to 1 dimensional array?

For example, suppose we are given an array:

```
char[][] 2dArray = new char[4][4];
```

In 2-dimensional space, the range `(0,0),(2,2)` would represent 9 elements (represented as O below):

`O, O, O, X
O, O, O, X
O, O, O, X
X, X, X, X`

If we represent the two-dimensional array as a 1-dimensional array:

```
char[] 1dArray = new char[16];
```

it would look like this:

```
O, O, O, X, O, O, O, X, O, O, O, X, X, X, X, X
```

I already know that I can find the index of a single point in my 1-dimensional array via the formula: `(rows * x + y)`.

i.e. the 2d point `(2,3)` would map to the 1d index `11` in the given example.

Given a pair of **2D** coordinates, How can I map a rectangular section of points to a **1D** array? I prefer not to use loop nesting, if possible.

Comment: You ask for a solution without nested loops and accept one using nested loops... well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let assume rectangular 2D array of `chars` like these:

```cpp
const int xs=6; // columns
const int ys=4; // rows
char dat2D_xy[xs][ys]=
    {
    "06ci",
    "17dj",
    "28ek",
    "39fl",
    "4agm",
    "5bhn",
    };
char dat2D_yx[ys][xs]=
    {
    "012345",
    "6789ab",
    "cdefgh",
    "ijklmn",
    };
dat2D_xy[5][3] == dat2D_yx[3][5] == 'n';
```

Then to convert `x,y` coordinates to 1D index and back you can use:

```cpp
i=x+(xs*y);
x=i%xs;
y=i/xs;
```

Or this:

```cpp
i=y+(ys*x);
x=i%ys;
y=i/ys;
```

Does not matter which it just changes the order of items in the 1D array. To copy whole array to 1D you need to use 2 nested loops or just single one with addition to DMA or any other memory transfer. Something like this:

```cpp
int i,x,y;
char dat1D[xs*ys];
for (i=0,y=0;y<ys;y++)
 for (x=0;x<xs;x++,i++)
  dat1D[i]=dat2D_xy[x][y];
//dat1D[i]=dat2D_yx[y][x];

//dat1D[]="0123456789abcdefghijklmn";
```

or:

```cpp
int i,x,y;
for (i=0,x=0;x<xs;x++)
 for (y=0;y<ys;y++,i++)
  dat1D[i]=dat2D_xy[x][y];
//dat1D[i]=dat2D_yx[y][x];

//dat1D[]="06ci17dj28ek39fl4agm5bhn";
```

There are no `X` needed ... unless you want to add also the null termination characters at the end of each row/line to ease up debug view or process rows or columns as strings. In such case you add `+1` for line size and add your termination character.

Comment: When using nested loops and performance matters, it is better to use the inner loop for the columns (as in the last code fragment) for most languages, because then you scan the array naturally, otherwise you are making jumps in memory.

Comment: @maraca conversion time is not as important as the final 1D array access pattern/usage as the conversion is done usually just once but the access is dome many times over .... but yes sequential access is usually faster

Answer (score 0):

It is easy, first decide for a storage order (column major or row major), then with a nested loop you fill from 2D matrix `A` the 1D array `B`:

**Example:**

`A` is a `NxM` matrix

```
for i in 
    for j in M
        B[i*M + j] = A[i][j]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need some language features if you don't want neseted loop.
This is my example in python.

First lets create a list `a` of dimension `4 x 4` where `a[i][j]` is a tuple of `(i, j)`

```
a = [[(i, j) for j in range(4)]for i in range(4)]
```

Now suppose we only want the submatrix from `(1, 1)` to `(2, 3)`. 
First lets filter elements from row 1 to row 2

`rows = a[1:3]`

Then we get the elements between col 1 and col 3 to get the submatrix.

`submatrix = [row[1:4] for row in rows]`

Now we have the submatrix, to convert it to 1d list, we can use `sum`

`ans = sum(submatrix, [])`

Finally if we print `ans`, we will have

`[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]`

Combining things together, we have this function, where `a` is the input matrix, `p1` and `p2` are input points for locating the submatrix

```
def f(a, p1, p2):
    x1, y1 = p1
    x2, y2 = p2

    return sum([row[y1:y2 + 1] for row in a[x1:x2 + 1]], [])
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible without nested loop and no language support (and wasn't mentioned yet), but I doubt it will be faster (array with n rows and m columns):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n * m; i++)
    arr1D[i] = arr2D[i / m][i % m];
```

The modulo obviously gives 0, 1, 2, ..., m - 1 and then starts at 0 again, as it should and the result of the integer division is increased by one after a row is full. Or to read column by column (worse in most languages, better read row by row as above):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n * m; i++)
    arr1D[i] = arr2D[i % n][i / n];
```

However this works only with rectangular matrices. Counter example:

```
int[][] arr2D = new int[2][];
arr2D[0] = new int[1];
arr2D[1] = new int[2];
```

In this case it would be best to do it in the standard way, using a list here because I don't know what the length of the result is going to be (add null checks if null is a possibility):

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < arr2D.lengh; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < arr2D[i].length; j++)
        list.add(arr2D[i][j]);
```